# Merging Rest datasets in Federation with resolvers?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-federation

pretty new to GraphQL and Apollo Federation.

I have a question, is it possible to populate one dataset with another such as:

```
# in Shop Service
type carId {
 id: Int
}

type Shop @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID!
  name: String
  carIds: [CarId]
}
```

```
# in Car Service
type Car {
  id: ID!
  name: String
}
extends type Shop @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
  cars: [Car]
}
```

**Car Resolver**

```
Query{...},
Shop: {
    async cars(shop, _, { dataSources }) {
      console.log(shop); // Issue here is it returns the references that are an object only holding the `id` key of the shop, I need the `cars` key here, to pass to my CarsAPI
      return await dataSources.CarsAPI.getCarsByIds(shop.carsIds);
    }
  }
```

From the Shop rest api the response would look like:

```
[{id: 1, name: "Brians Shop", cars: [1, 2, 3]}, {id: 2, name: "Ada's shop", cars: [4,5,6]}]
```

From the Car rest api the response would look like:

```
[{id: 1, name: "Mustang"}, {id: 2, name: "Viper"}, {id: 3, name: "Boaty"}]
```

So what I want to archive is to query my GraphQL server for:

```
Shop(id: 1) {
  id
  name
  cars {
    name
 }
}
```

And then expect:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Brian's shop",
  cars: [
    {name: "Mustang"},
    {name: "Viper"},
    {name: "Boaty"}
  ]
}
```

Is this possible, it was what I thought when I chose federation :)

Comment: Your question is a little bit confusing. 1) What's extend type "Service"? 2) You said that you need the "cars" key inside the resolver that returns actually defines it?

Comment: @edmundo, 1. Type error should have been “extend type Shop” that is now corrected. 2. I want to take the “carIds” and turn them into actual cars. In the shop service I have access to the ids they come from the rest response, then I want to extend that shop by extending the data from the Car service, therefore I resolve the Shop.cars in the Car service because I can fetch cars based of the shop.carIds, my issue is I don’t know how I can pass the Shop.carIds to Car service.

Comment: Also sorry for the confusion in the Resolver it should say getCarsById(Shop.carIds) that is fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly after your comments, what you want is to have the `carIds` from Shop service coming in your Car service inside the `cars` resolver.

You can make use of the `@requires` directive which will instruct Apollo Server that you need a field (or a couple of) before it starts executing the `cars` resolver. That is:

**Car Service**

```
extend type Shop @key(fields: "id") {
  id: ID! @external
  carIds: [Int] @external
  cars: [Car] @requires(fields: "carIds")
}
```

Now, inside the `cars` resolver, you should be able to access `shop.carIds` on your first parameter.

See: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/federation/advanced-features/#computed-fields

Comment: Thanks man this totally saved my day! And thanks for finding the docs on computed keys i could not find them!